# Is there a method to iterate through all documents in a collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the firestore of firebase and I want to iterate through the whole collection. Is there something like:

```
db.collection('something').forEach((doc) => {
  // do something
})
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can simply query the collection for all its documents using the get() method on the collection reference.  A CollectionReference object subclasses Query, so you can call Query methods on it.  By itself, a collection reference is essentially an unfiltered query for all of its documents.

Android: [Query.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get())

iOS/Swift: [Query.getDocuments()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#getdocumentscompletion)

JavaScript: [Query.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get)

In each platform, this method is asynchronous, so you'll have to deal with the callbacks correctly.

See also the product documentation for "[Get all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)".

Comment: How can get the same in python? Can't find any.

Comment: @jay There are python samples in the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 8):

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Comment: What is that .then(function(querySnapshot)?

Comment: By doing this you'll get a shallow collection, right? (doc.data won't return its children documents), What if I have children documents within cities? (I.E neighborhoods), how can I get the values from those children?

Answer (score 8):

If you know that there aren't too many docs in the collection (e.g. thousands or millions) then you can just use `collectionRef.get()` as described in the top-voted answer here and explained in Firebase [docs](https://github.com/proficientai/firewalk).

However, in many cases, a collection can contain large numbers of documents that you can't just "get" at once, as your program's memory usage will explode. In these cases, you need to implement a different traversal logic that will go through the entire collection by batches. You also need to ensure that you don’t miss any documents or process any of them multiple times.

This is why we wrote [Firewalk](https://github.com/proficientai/firewalk) at [Proficient AI](https://proficientai.com). Firewalk is an open-source Node.js library that *walks* you through a given collection/traversable. It is an extremely light, robust, well-typed, and well-documented library that provides you with configurable traverser objects that walk you through a given collection.

You can find the Github repo [here](https://github.com/proficientai/firewalk) and the documentation [here](https://firewalk.proficientai.com). Also, here's a short snippet that shows you how you would traverse a `users` collection with [Firewalk](https://github.com/proficientai/firewalk).

```js
import { createTraverser } from 'firewalk';

const usersCollection = firestore().collection('users');
const traverser = createTraverser(usersCollection);

const { batchCount, docCount } = await traverser.traverse(async (batchDocs, batchIndex) => {
  const batchSize = batchDocs.length;
  await Promise.all(
    batchDocs.map(async (doc) => {
      const { email, firstName } = doc.data();
      await sendEmail({ to: email, content: `Hello ${firstName}!` });
    })
  );
  console.log(`Batch ${batchIndex} done! We emailed ${batchSize} users in this batch.`);
});

console.log(`Traversal done! We emailed ${docCount} users in ${batchCount} batches!`);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is large and memory is a concern but you do not want to use a library here is a snippet I wrote in node to perform a data migration for collections in batches:

```js
import firebase from "firebase-admin";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const processCollectionInBatches = async (collectionName) => {
    let lastDoc = undefined;
    const limit = 1000;

    while (true) {
        const snapshot = lastDoc ?
            await getFirestore().collection(collectionName)
                .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
                .startAfter(lastDoc.id)
                .limit(limit)
                .get() :
            await getFirestore().collection(collectionName)
                .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
                .limit(limit)
                .get();

        if (!snapshot.docs.length) {
            // no more documents found
            break;
        }

        // process batch
        snapshot.docs.forEach(async (doc) => {
            // process each document here
        });

        lastDoc = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
    }
};
```

Comment: Regarding the process batch block, a foreach loop using async is probably not doing what you would expect it to do, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop