# How to update firebase document data onclick in vuetify project

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, click, vuetify.js

I recently completed a [vuetify tutorial by the Net Ninja on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uZYKcKHgU0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g0MQZfHwKcuB0Yswgb3gA5) and created a todo list. Now I want to be able to click on a 'mark as complete' button in a task to access my firebase collection (called 'projects') and update the corresponding document field (status) with the value 'complete'. I've been able to use [query.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495026/is-there-a-method-to-iterate-through-all-documents-in-a-collection-in-firestore) and display the correct document data in my console, but I don't know how I can update the document at this point.

This is the button that is part of a v-for loop that renders out my content:

```
<v-btn v-if="project.status !== 'complete'" @click="updateData(project.title)" class="success ml-0">Mark as complete <v-icon right>check</v-icon></v-btn>
```

I can use this method to get the data from the correct document and log it into the console:

```
updateData(projectTitle){
    db.collection("projects").where("title", "==", projectTitle)
    .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
          console.log(doc.id, " = >", doc.data());
        });
      })  
  }
```

I'm just not sure how to actually update the document from here. I've been able to use this line to update a document by including the really long document 'codename'...

```
db.collection('projects').doc('tjwnZZHGDkZWJxpXMdHj').update({
  status: 'complete'
})
```

But is there a way to modify that line slightly and insert it in the querySnapshot function? If not, how could I update the selected document within the querySnapshot function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `querySnapshot` includes `DocumentSnaphots`. From these you can get `DocumentReference` and on it you call `.update()`

---

Result should looks like this:

```
updateData(projectTitle){
    db.collection("projects").where("title", "==", projectTitle)
    .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
          doc.ref.update({status: 'complete'});
        });
      })  
  }
```

It should works, then i would consider using `batch` requests. (Also i updated to `async/await`). Maximum of `batch` is 500 operations. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

```
async updateData(projectTitle){
    var batch = db.batch();
    var querySnapshot = await db.collection("projects")
                                .where("title", "==", projectTitle)
                                .get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
          batch.update(doc.ref, { status: 'complete'});
    });
    batch.commit();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Dominik!