# firebase iterate trough a collection and update all documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to iterate through a collection and update the documents. I have found this post: [Is there a method to iterate through all documents in a collection in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495026/is-there-a-method-to-iterate-through-all-documents-in-a-collection-in-firestore)
there is shown how to read the data. I rewrote this code to update the documents. But it doesn't seem to work because I need to write the data:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users_highscores").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.update({
            highscores_daily: {}
        })
     });
  });
```

I get this error: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc.update is not a function**

I think to iterate and write the data I need to do something fundamentally different but I don't now what. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I just had the idea to read the id and then write to this id. It is probably not the most effective way to do this but it works:

```
   db.collection("users_highscores").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            db.collection("users_highscores").doc(doc.id).update({
                highscore_daily: {}
            })
        });
    });
```

But I would like to see something more effective that doesn't waste any reads.